# Displaying values from a database on different rows in a textbox C#

Tags: c#, mysql, textbox, rows

I've been working on this program where it will pull accounts out of the database and will display them in a textbox I got this working so far but it will only pull the account from my database on the first row. Here is my code :

```
 string myConnection = "datasource=xxxx;port=3306;username=xxxx;password=xxxx!";
        string Query = "select * from xxx.xxx;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try 
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
             myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
             while (myReader.Read())
             {
                 string sUsername = myReader.GetString("usernames");
                 string sPasswords = myReader.GetString("passwords");
                 nsTextBox1.Text = sUsername + ":" + sPasswords;



             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Also is there anyway so it will erase the old Username + Password and show the new one that is pulled?

Comment: It's probably displaying the last user name, try nsTextBox1.Text += sUsername + ":" + sPasswords;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?:

```
nsTextBox1.Text += sUsername + ":" + sPasswords + Enviroment.NewLine;
```

Also, your TextBox needs to be multiline.

Must it be a TextBox? Why not use a ListBox?